# Is there a core C# Rectangle class that's not read-only where it shouldn't?

Tags: c#

The **`Point`** has `X` and `Y` and they can be changed. But the **`Rectangle`** has the `Left`, `Top`, `Right`, `Bottom` read-only. And to make things even more entertaining, the `Width` and `Height` are writable. So to move a `Rectangle`, you need to `Offset` and change `Width` and `Height` when you could just change the `TLRB` values accordingly.

**Is there any real `Rectangle` class I'm missing that has these values writable so I don't have to get creative when updating internal values? Like `RECT`?**

**PS**: Currently using `Rectangle.FromLTRB` but I'm typing way more than I should to just change the `Top` value.

Comment: just create a new instance and assign it in place of the old one - both `Point` and `RectangleF` are structs so *should* be immutable

Comment: Wrapper method or extension method?

Comment: @BrokenGlass `Point` has `X` and `Y` writable. `Rectangle` has the equivalent members `TLRB` read-only. What immutable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are missing something. 
Top is read only but it is only

```
public int Top
{
    get
    {
        return this.Y;
    }
}
```

Y is writeable. So if you want to change Top simply change Y.

```
public int Left
{
    get
    {
        return this.X;
    }
}
```

X is writeable. Width and Height are also writeable. If you stick to Top == Y/Left == X  + Width + Height you can alter an existing Rectangle (System.Drawing Rectangle I guess) without any problems.

Comment: *YES!* I knew I was missing something. I'm so used to `TLRB` from `RECT` that I didn't even notice the others. **Thanks!** *PS: Best hiding place is in plain sight... absolutely!*

Comment: Ah, so there __is__ a difference after all between Top & Y etc.. I always wondered, but never bothered looking it up..

Comment: `X` and `Y` are analogous to `Left` and `Top` but `Width` and `Height` are **not** analogous to `Right` and `Bottom` - the latter are *calculated* values. It should be possible to set `Right` and `Bottom` directly and have the width and height contract/expand automatically in response, but it isn't, because .NET's Rectangle implementation is deficient. Therefore this question is valid and still stands: is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 3):

[`System.Drawing.Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) has these set-able public properties `X`, `Y`, `Width`, `Height`.

The non-set-able properties are `Top`, `Bottom`, `Left,` and `Right`. Though these are all indirectly set-able via the set-able properties. If you review the `Rectangle` MSDN article linked above you can see how the non-set-able properties are calculated.

- `Top` is just `Y`.
- `Bottom` is just `Y` - `Height`
- `Left` is just `X`.
- `Right` is just the x component `X` + `Width`.

I think that you can do everything you need to within the already defined `Rectangle` class by setting the set-able properties with the way that the other non-set-able properties are calculated.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It seems that you were right and a better solution was provided, in a different situation you could have written you own Rectangle class:

```
class Point
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
}

class Rectangle
{
    public Point TopLeft;
    public double Width;
    public double Height;
}
```

Then you can create methods to return the points if you want. You could have as well made this class a wrapper around the original class if you wanted to modify its behaviour.

Comment: I know, that's why I asked if there's anything in core. Having to write a writable `Rectangle` just because somebody made a design decision drunk... is not that great of an alternative. Having only used C# for 7 days now *(C++ for 15 years)*, was wondering if there's anything I'm missing...

Comment: You could try to scrape the Rectangle and use it for your own implementation. Are you talking about `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle` or another Rectangle class ?

Comment: @BlueTrin seems to be [System.Drawing.Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
Rectangle initialRect;

....some other code


initialRect = new Rectangle(new Point(0,0), 100, 100);
```

or

```
initialRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

or

```
//include offset as needed.
initialRect = new Rectangle(initial.X, initial.Y, initial.Width, initial.Height);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the System.Drawing.Rectangle struct, it has writable X and Y properties just like Point.

Comment: But modifying X and Y *shifts* the rectangle. I believe he wants properties that just modify the top, bottom, left, or right, while keeping the others intact.